# How to show different ViewControllers when tapping on tabBar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, presentviewcontroller

I have three viewControllers and two of them connected to a tabBarController. So app should show one of the two vc’s depending Bool value when tapping on tabBar item [here is my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TKPu.png)

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
      
        
    }
    
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let userLoggedIn: Bool!
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1{
            if userLoggedIn == true{
                // show firstVC
            }else{
                // show secondVC
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! i',m using storyboard to make UI

Comment: Did you try to setup self.selectedIndex in viewWillAppear of TabBarController ?  And how do you initialize userLoggedIn ?

Comment: userLoggenIn is a just example. i will get bool value from userDefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add .overCurrentContext to modalPresentationStyle in your viewDidLoad like this.

```
 let newVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"secondVC")
 newVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
 self.present(newVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use childViewController with the parent is ViewController fromStoryboard.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       ///add two ChildVC here, hide 1 ifneeded
    }
```

When click to this tab you check `userLoggedIn`.

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if userLoggedIn == true {
               /// show first childVC
               /// hide second childVC
         } else {
                /// hide first childVC
               /// show second childVC
         }
    }
```

You can check demo: [Demo](https://github.com/vienvu/DemoChangeChildOnTabbar)

Comment: how can i initialise childVC. and don't forget that i have thirdVC that should stay independently

Comment: and all view controllers have their UI and code so i don't want to rebuild UI of each VC

Comment: @ you just init childVC controller and add to this. You don't need to rebuild, just re-structure the code

Comment: so can u show how initialise childVC because i'm very new to programming and i have no idea how to do it

Comment: @ ok I will create an example for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot. waiting for example

Comment: @ you can check my demo.

Comment: Sorry but looks like you don't understand my mission. bool value set's in `userDefaults`. so when tapping on a first tabbar item, app should show VC1 or VC3 `without losing tabBar`. and it will be a good approach to use function that i defined in my question. (i implemented storyboard with plan)

Comment: @ yeah, I understand you mean, in my example, just show for you how tabbar change on userlogin. Actually you can get it anywhere. I just show my idea on your case

Comment: yes thank u. can we make something like second answer because it's not currently working

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the viewController list when the userLoggedIn variable is modified (assuming userLoggedIn is TabBarCOntroller instance variable) :

```
class TabBarC: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet var firstVC : FirstViewController!
    @IBOutlet var secondVC : SecondViewController!
    @IBOutlet var thirdVC : ThirdViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        for vc in self.viewControllers! {
            if let fv = vc as? FirstViewController {
                firstVC = fv
            } else if let fv = vc as? SecondViewController  {
                secondVC = fv
            } else if let fv = vc as? ThirdViewController  {
                thirdVC = fv
            }
        }
    }


    var userLoggedIn : Bool = false {
        didSet {
        if userLoggedIn {
            self.viewControllers = [firstVC, thirdVC]
        } else {
            self.viewControllers = [secondVC, thirdVC]
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self. userLoggedIn = false
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if item.tag == 3 { // For purpose of test i set tag for 3 VC to 1 for firsttVC, 2 for secondVC, 3 for thirdVC
            // for test : change login value each time thirdVC is selected
            userLoggedIn = ! userLoggedIn
        }
    }
```

So each time from anywhere in your code you setup userLoggedIn, the tabor show the wanted tab bar items.
The 3 VC are added to the tabbar in the stpryboard.
When selecting thirdVC, the first tab bar item changes between one and two

Comment: your idea look's great but nothing changes on screen

Comment: can it happen because i already have working tabbarcontroller with connected VC's in storyboard ?

Comment: Just 1 thing : you need to initialise userLoggedIn somewhere in code (viewWillAppear for example)  to make the first state for the tabbar : the didSet is not called during the init phase but only when value is modified later). You should also add the 3 VC in the tabbar in the storyboard.

Comment: i already defined userStatus in VC2 by userDefaults.

Comment: @Plit Xav. i restructured my code as u said. noting changes on screen

Comment: I added some code for the tab bar controller

Comment: i having error in item.tag line. maybe i should set tag somewhere?

Comment: and should i connect ibo outlets in stroryboard?

Comment: I add VC initialisation in the code in viewDidLoad, so need to connect. The code lists the view controllers and then saves access to firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC according to there type.

Comment: @Plit Xav. thank for your idea and help. but i already finded issue by the other way and added it as answer. thank u